# Apply implicit function theorem on partial solution to Lagrangian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose $\mathcal{L} = f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y,z)$ where $z$ is actually constant which I would like to take to use implicit function on.

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = f_x(x,y)+\lambda g_x(x,y,z)=0$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = f_y(x,y)+\lambda g_y(x,y,z)=0$$
After rearrange the euquation, I have 
$$F(x,y,z) =\frac{f_x(x,y)}{f_y(x,y)} - \frac{ g_x(x,y,z)}{ g_y(x,y,z)} = 0 $$
Can I apply implicit function on $F(x,y,z)$ to find $\frac{dx}{dz}$?

Comment: Yes, with appropriate assumptions on the functions involved.  But if you only wish to determine the sign of the effect, you might want to see if you can apply Topkis' Theorem.

Comment: notice that $f_y$ or $g_y$ might be zero...